# Laravel 5 shows 500 Internal Server public/index.php not calling

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have download code from git and install dependencies using composer. This setup is running perfectly on my windows xampp but not running on live server.

On live linux server public/index.php file not calling.
I have done already following solutions

1. Give permission 777 to storage,public folder
2. give group permission to storage
3. change .env file settings
4. debug mode true

anything not working please help ?

Comment: Did you checked your .htaccess file.

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

Try this code instead of your default .htaccess

Comment: you must apply 777 permission to bootstrap/cache/ folder

Comment: thx for reply There was laravel version issue. For laravel 5.1 PHP >= 5.5.9